# C++ ООП имплементация событий

Tags: c++

Как в C++ имплементировать обработку событий? Я создал класс Button и мне нужно обьекту моего класса сказать какие действия ему надо совершить и еще передать в обработчик второй обьект с которым это дело надо совершить

Comment: а класс Button - это просто класс, или он оборачивает реальную кнопку gui-фреймворка? (нужны детали)

Comment: В C++ нет встроенных механизмов, поддерживающих события и их обработку. Т.е. всё нужно реализовывать самому, либо же искать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: @KoVadim оборачивает Gtk::Button (gtkmm)

Comment: смотрите предыдущий вопрос

Comment: @ixSci я понял и мне нужен простой пример имплементации или направление куда смотреть

Comment: Простого примера не получится, а смотреть можно в сторону boost.signals или Qt. Qt лучше, но это целая библиотека со своей философией, boost.signals убоги, но что делать? Можно ещё погуглить библиотеки, их должно быть много. Разной степени паршивости.

Comment: Пример работы с сигналами в Gtk https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-signals.html